# Make K different (cardinality) google OR-TOOLS

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm wondering if there is a generalisation of solver.AllDifferent(x) in google or-tools that allows for the specification of how many different elements I allow.

So if len(x) = 4, then AllDifferent(x) means that len(set(x)) = 4. But what if I just want to enforce "at least 2 different", so: len(set(x)) >=2 ?

Is there a constraint that generalises AllDifferent to be able to set the cardinality of the solution variable ?

Comment: I am curious. What is the reason you want this?

Comment: I was trying to do this example on my own: https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling 
and the constraint "No shift is staffed by more than two different nurses in a week."  is this kind of constraint.

Comment: That would have been a better question as I don't think `AllDifferent` is the right paradigm for this.

Comment: There is a global constraint called "nvalue" that checks/enforces the number of distinct values in an array. See http://www.emn.fr/x-info/sdemasse/gccat/Cnvalue.html

What I know of, there's no built-in support for this constraint in or-tools.

Comment: Just create bool vars fo each x[i] == j, then have value[j] = max(x[i] == j), then sum(value[j]) >= 2. This works fine with CP-SAT.  In that case the max can be implemented with implications and one big clause.